# finding invariant lines, I can't figure out what's wrong with my working

Tags: matrices, graph-invariants

[image]

**My working**

I multiplied the matrix with the matrix $(x, y)$ and named the resultant matrix $(x', y')$

I got:
$y' = mx' +c$

$y = mx + c$

(since they both lie on the same line)

$x + 2y = x'$

$5y = y'$

(by multipling the $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\6 & 5\end{bmatrix}$ with $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ and comparing the results to $\begin{bmatrix}x' \\ y'\end{bmatrix}$

well I solved both of them and I got $-2m^{2}x + 4mx -2mc +4c = 0$
I wrote this a bunch of different ways and got "($m = 0$ and $c = 0$) or ($x = 0$ and $c =0$)"
which I summed up into "$c = 0$ and ($m=0$ or $x=0$)"

which results in $y = 0 + 0$ ($mx = 0$ since we know either $m$ or $x$ is $0$ so $mx$ will always be $0$)

well $y = 0$ isn't the answer so where is my working wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You missed out the term $6x$ when multiplying $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\6 & 5\end{bmatrix}$ with $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$. It should be

$$x+2y=x' \quad (1)$$
$$\color{red}{6x}+5y=y' \quad (2)$$

Then you can substitute $y=mx+c$ for both expression, use $y'=mx'+c$ to substitute $(1)$ into $(2)$ and find the required values.